# Visual Studio 2019 C++ multiline comments

Tags: c++, visual-studio, comments, visual-studio-2019

When a line is partially selected, this results in `/**/` C-style comment:

```
#include /*<assert.h>*/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <node.h>
```

When one or several lines is partially selected, this results in `//` C++-style comment:

```
//#include <assert.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
#include <node.h>
```

All VS2019 comment options have this behaviour: **Toggle Line Comment** (`Ctrl+K, Ctrl+/`), **Toggle Block Comment** (`Ctrl+Shift+/`), **Comment Selection** (`Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C`).

Do these options behave differently in other languages?

I'm aware of C++-style comment drawbacks but would like to be able to use them for multiline comments where needed:

```
/*
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
*/
#include <node.h>
```

Is it possible to configure Visual Studio 2019 this way?

There are other similar questions but they refer to older VS versions and answers seem to be outdated.

Comment: *"Is it possible to configure Visual Studio 2019 this way?"* - Maybe, maybe not. You never explained, what *"this way"* is, so we don't know.

Comment: Use them to do *what*, precisely? If you don't explain what you expect to happen, we cannot help you.

Comment: @IInspectable I would like to use VS to create C-style `/**/` multiline comments without writing `/*` and `*/` manually, preferably with built-in VS shortcuts but any option that allows to not write them manually will work for me. I'm fond of precise and clear questions but I'm not sure how I can make myself more clear.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, you should select the whole line (i.e. from the very first character of the line) in order to use c++ comments for multiple lines.

If there are comments among the selected lines, Ctrl+K,Ctrl+C will generate C++ style comments even if the selection does not start from the beginning of the lines.

For example:Select the content as shown:

[image]

And then `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C`

[image]

If you select the whole line including spaces:

[image]

And then `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C`，you will get C++-style comment for multiline comments

[image]

Comment: Thanks for explaining the behaviour of VS. Unfortunately, this doesn't fully answer the question because the approach won't work for unindented lines like shown in the OP.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, if you select the whole line (from the very first character of the line), you couldn't use VS to create C-style /**/multiline comments.It may be a characteristic of comments, and has nothing to do with shortcut.